# Room TypeConverter for Custom Object in Java

Tags: java, android, android-room, typeconverter

This is my custom object:

```
public class Proceeding {

    @SerializedName("code")
    private String code;

    @SerializedName("hasAccount")
    private boolean hasAccount;

    @SerializedName("description")
    private String description;

    @SerializedName("pricePattern")
    private String pricePattern;

    // Getters & Setters ...
}
```

I need a TypeConverter class for Room and this is my TypeConverter class:

```
public class ProceedingTypeConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    public static Proceeding fromString(String value) {
        Type type = new TypeToken<String>() {
        }.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(value, type);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromObject(Proceeding obj) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(obj);
    }
}
```

but I'm getting error in `return new Gson().fromJson(value, type);` line.

Error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

How can I solve the problem?

**UPDATE:**
I changed my TypeConverter class to:

```
public class ProceedingTypeConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    public Proceeding fromString(String value) {
        return new Gson().fromJson(value, Proceeding.class);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromObject(Proceeding obj) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(obj);
    }
}
```

but I'm still getting error when I Call API:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 3125 path $[0].store
```

Comment: You don't need type cast

public  Proceeding fromString(String value) {
            return new Gson().fromJson(value, Proceeding.class);
        }

use this code. it will work.

Comment: No No No...!!! @ShohelRana Runtime error has been solved but I'm getting this error when I Call API: `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 3125 path $[0].store`

Comment: This error will be happend when your respone json and gson model is not same. Can you please share your json file